# Trying to plot a bar chart using pycharm

Tags: python, pandas

```
x=stan2['Month']
y=stan2['distance_kms']
plt.tite('Distance per month')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabl('distance_kms')
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

That is my code. But I am getting the following error. What could be the problem?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:\Python\PROJECTS\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> KeyError: 'Month'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "E:\Python\PROJECTS\main.py", line 21, in 
> x=stan2['Month']
> File "E:\Python\PROJECTS\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
> File "E:\Python\PROJECTS\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err
> KeyError: 'Month'

Comment: there seems to be a typo line 3: `plt.title()`

Comment: there seems to be a typo line 5: `plt.ylabel()`

Answer (score 0):

Testing out some scenarios with your code and a simple data frame, the likeliest issue is that your data frame column name is not actually 'Month'.  You might want to double check that including the proper upper and lower case letters.  When I ran the following code snippet, I got the identical error.  Note the case difference.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stan2 = pd.DataFrame([['Jan', 24000], ['Feb', 32000], ['Mar', 115362]], columns=['month', 'distance_kms'])

x=stan2['Month']
y=stan2['distance_kms']
plt.title('Distance per month')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('distance_kms')
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()

File "/home/craig/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Month'
```

When I made sure the column names matched in the data frame to the x and y assignments, I received a barchart.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stan2 = pd.DataFrame([['Jan', 24000], ['Feb', 32000], ['Mar', 115362]], columns=['Month', 'distance_kms'])

x=stan2['Month']
y=stan2['distance_kms']
plt.title('Distance per month')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('distance_kms')
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Barchart]

I hope that helps.

Regards.